# Select and Insert MySQL with distinct record

Tags: mysql

```
INSERT INTO numbers (type, number) 
VALUES 'telephone', SELECT DISTINCT tel FROM flat_data
```

I am attempting to select distinct numbers from one table and then insert them into another table.

However I need to manually set the `type` column that I am inserting into manually.

I can do it without the `DISTINCT` but I can't get my head around how to do it with!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
INSERT INTO numbers (type, number) 
SELECT DISTINCT 'telephone', tel 
FROM flat_data
```

Comment: Thanks - I must have tried every permutation of this but that - so stupid! will accept when can.